# independent probability

Tags: probability

> One had decided to split is money between 3 investors, each one of the investor randomly and independent of the other investors choose to invest in 1 stock out of 20.
>   
>   There the following events:
>   
>   $B_{1,2}$= the 1st investor and the 2nd invest in the same stock 
>   
>   $B_{1,3}$= the 1st investor and the 3rd invest in the same stock
>   
>   $B_{2,3}$= the 2nd investor and the 3rd invest in the same stock
>
> Are those event independent pairwise? are they independent?

The given answer is: 

$P(B_{i,j,(i\neq j)})$=$\frac{1}{20}$

 $P(B_{1,2}\cap B_{1,3})=P(B_{2,3}\cap B_{1,3})=P(B_{2,3}\cap B_{1,2})=\frac{1}{400}$

 $P(B_{2,3}|B_{1,2}\cap B_{1,3})=1\neq P(B_{2,3})$

How can $P(B_{i,j,(i\neq j)})$=$\frac{1}{20}$? we know that $P(B_{i})=P(B_{j})=\frac{1}{20}$ so $P(B_{i,j})=\frac{1}{20}*\frac{1}{20}$ but on the other hand if an investor chooses a stock the other have to choose the same one so $P(B_{i,j})=\frac{20}{20*20}=\frac{1}{20}$

Comment: You use $B_i$ with two different meanings in that sentence; it hadn't been introduced with either of them. In your second usage, you seem to be referring to an event -- which event? (Also, you equate an event to a number; the left-hand side should be the probability of that event instead.)

Comment: the event is that both investor choose the same stock, I am trying to check if it is independent.

Comment: That makes no sense -- $B_i$ can't be the event that both investors choose the same stock. (And if it is: then what is $B_j$?)

Comment: @gbox :  Agreed that $B_{i,j}$ is the event "i and j choose the same stock".  What event is $B_i$ ?

Comment: $B=$ the stock "name" and $_{i}=$ the investor

Comment: Please take a minute or two to think this through. It makes no sense, and people won't be able to help you unless you write it down clearly. With your last comment above, your formulation "The probability that $B_i$ and $B_j$ will choose the same stock" makes no sense -- how can a stock indexed by an investor choose a stock?

Comment: By the way, the usual expression for what you've translated as "independent in couples" is "pairwise independent".

Comment: @joriki I added the book answer, so it may help, although I do not answered how the got to the answer

Comment: If you've copied the given answer correctly, you should consider using a different textbook (or course). The answer equates an event to a number.

Comment: @joriki sorry that was my fault I have fixed that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25653/discussion-between-gbox-and-joriki).

Comment: Sorry, I have no time to chat, I'm about to go out. I suggest that you take some time to read through the comments without haste and try to correct all the inconsistencies that I pointed out; most of them are still there.

Comment: Note that there can't be an event **$B_i$**, since investor *i* can't choose the *same* stock in isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events are pairwise independent if 
$$
P(B_{i, j} \cap B_{k, l}) = P(B_{i, j})P(B_{k, l}) \quad i \neq j, k \neq l
$$
for each pair $B_{i, j}$, $B_{k, l}$ in the list. Each event $\{ B_{i, j} \cap B_{k, l} \}$ corresponds to all three investors choosing the same stock, which has probability 
$$
P(B_{i, j} \cap B_{k, l}) = 20 \cdot\frac{1}{20^3} = \frac{1}{400}
$$
since each investor chooses independently. We also have $$P(B_{i, j}) = 20 \cdot \frac{1}{20^2} $$ so evidently $P(B_{i, j} \cap B_{k, l}) = P(B_{i, j})P(B_{k, l})$ holds. For independence we need
$$
P(B_{1, 2}\cap B_{1, 3}\cap B_{2, 3}) = P(B_{1, 2})P(B_{1, 3})(B_{2, 3})
$$
But if you think about it, the event $\{ B_{1, 2}\cap B_{1, 3}\cap B_{2, 3}\} $ is the same event as any pair $\{ B_{i, j} \cap B_{k, l} \}$ because if $1$ and $2$ choose the same stock and $2$ and $3$ choose the same stock then it follows that $1$ and $3$ also choose the same stock. Hence
$$
P(B_{1, 2}\cap B_{1, 3}\cap B_{2, 3})  = \frac{1}{400} \neq P(B_{1, 2})P(B_{1, 3})(B_{2, 3}) = \frac{1}{20^3}
$$
and hence we do not have independence.

Comment: $$P(B_{i, j}) = 20 \cdot \frac{1}{20^2} $$  This is because $|\Omega|=20*20$ The event $A$ of the first and the second choosing the same stock is $|A|=20*1$? (the first has 20 options and the second has 1 option?)

Comment: @gbox That is one way to reason, yes. If you define a sample space for the outcome of choices between two of the investors, say denote each outcome by $(S_i, S_j)$ where the first element is the choice of  investor 1 and the second of investor 2, then you have $400$ different pairs where $20$ of them have $i=j$. Another way is to say that the event is the same as the first investor picking any stock and the second having to pick that specific stock, i.e. investor 1 having 20 choices and the second only 1.

Answer (score 1):

*Revised Answer*

Revising answer as I got thoroughly confused by the terminological inexactitudes !

The key lies in the fact that **$B_{i,j}$** has been defined as investor *i* and investor *j*  investing in the **same** stock, not a **particular** stock, so *i* may invest in **any** stock, and *j* must invest in the **same** stock.

This explains **$P(B_{i,j,(i\neq j)}) = \frac{1}{20}$**, and

**$P(B_{1,2}\cap B_{1,3})=P(B_{2,3}\cap B_{1,3})=P(B_{2,3}\cap B_{1,2})=\frac{1}{400}$**

You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: You haven't addressed the question: whether the events $B_{i,j}$ are (pairwise) independent.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I have addressed your doubts in a revised answer. As I have commented in the comments part to your question, there can be no such event as **$B_i$**